# underline instead of space in tabbing environment

Tags: tabbing

I have following example

```
\begin{tabbing}
Person1: \underline{Long info about Person1} \=
Person2: \underline{Shorter info} \>
\end{tabbing}
```

I want to fill the gap in second line before the `\>` with an underline. I tryed

```
Person2: \underline{Shorter info}\hrulefill \>
```

but it didn't work out.

Comment: welcome. did you try `Person2: \underline{Shorter info }\>` yet?

Comment: Should the underline be connected to that of `\underline{Shorter info}` *without* showing a break? Note that `\underline` is put below the depth of its contents. Since `Shorter info` contains no descenders, it will be placed higher than that of `Longer info`.

Comment: Werner, underline height doesn't matter. The break in line after `underline{Shorter info}` is not desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code snippet, the following works, although it may require some tweaking for more complicated examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
Person1: \underline{Long info about Person1} \= \\
Person2: \underline{Shorter info} \> \\
Person2: rlap{\underline{\hphantom{Long info about Person1}}}Shorter info
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

The reason *why* this works is because `Person1` is similar in width to `Person2`. If this is not the case, you can always use an extra tab marker `\=` to identify this location.

`\rlap` allows for a `r`ight over`lap` (of width `0pt`), while `\hphantom` only takes the horizontal width into consideration (without typesetting anything). That is, no height, and therefore also no descenders. If you have descenders within `Shorter info`, a regular `\phantom` should suffice.

Here's an alternative view on something similar, this time using `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
First person: \hspace*{2em} \= \underline{Long info about Person1} \= \\
Second person: \> \underline{Shorter info} \> \\
Second person: \>\rlap{\underline{\hphantom{Long info about Person1}}}Shorter info
\end{tabbing}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\hspace*{2em}}l@{}}
  First person: & Long info about Person1 \\ \cline{2-2}
  Second person: & Shorter info \\ \cline{2-2}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You even don't need `tabbing` in this soolution. But you have to edit in 2 more places to change prson1's info. I thought that maybe there is a way to autpomatically fill those gaps using tabbing..

Comment: @VictorProon: I know, hence my statement about the width of `Person1` and `Person2`. I've added an alternative using `tabular`. Not entirely sure about the context of your usage, so these are just suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply add a space character to the `\underline{}` command:

```
\begin{tabbing}
 Person1: \underline{Long info about Person1} \=
 Person2: \underline{Shorter info }\>
\end{tabbing}
```

This works for me. Did I understand your question correctly? If not, please add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Look at Werner's comment. I want to get the effect similar to what happens in line3 of his example.

Comment: Got it, I'm off the track. Werner's answer looks good tho.