# Underline entire line in tabbing environment

Tags: underline, tabbing

Following on from the question [underline instead of space in tabbing environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59081/underline-instead-of-space-in-tabbing-environment), I would like to ask whether it is also possible to underline an entire line across a tab space.
Unfortunately, I have not been able to find an example that is in the context of the `tabbing` environment.
Here is my reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
Person1: \= \underline{Long info about Person1} \= \\
Person2: \> \underline{Shorter info} \> \\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

I would like the underlining to go over the whole second line, as in the following illustration:
[image]

Many thanks in advance!